# cosmos SDK 3 : concurrent initialization of null field?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

Consider this dummy class :

```
class Foo {
   public string id { get; set; }
   public List<int>? items { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to devise a proper way of working with field "items". **The difficulty is that it's nullable.**

Normally for a list you would add items like this :

```
     // Scenario A : basic append
     var po = PatchOperation.Add( "/items/-", foo ); // <-- notice the /-

     await _container.PatchItemAsync<Foo>(
        foo.id,
        "myPartitionKey",
        new[] { po },
        RequestOptions.DontReturnDataOnPatch);
```

But since the list is nullable it will throw a CosmosException (bad request) the first time.
first you need to do something like this :

```
     // Scenario B: creation
     var items = new List<int>() { foo };
     var po = PatchOperation.Add( "/items", items ); // <-- notice the absence of /-

     await _container.PatchItemAsync<Foo>(
        foo.id,
        "myPartitionKey",
        new[] { po },
        RequestOptions.DontReturnDataOnPatch);
```

It means you need to decide based on some initial reading of the item :

```
     var foo = await _container.ReadItemAsync(
        id,
        "myPartitionKey");
```

And then you can decide :

```
if (foo.items == null) {
   // Scenario B (creation)
   //...
} else {
   // Scenario A (append)
   // ...
}
```

**Now, my problem : Concurrency.**

The Cosmos SDK **is not "managed"** like would be, for example, EF.
It doesn't know if **another call stack** (in my case: this is all part of a Web API) has changed the value of foo.items in Cosmos **between the moment I read it and the moment I try to update it.**

Choosing the wrong method (between "create" and "append") will either result in a bad request or --worse-- will result in overwriting the items.

**Is there a pattern for that?**

Comment: @NotFound it was a design choice : the property is nullable. What I'm asking is a general answer to a general question.

Comment: fyi please be mindful of tags. Two of your 'cosmos' tags were unrelated to Cosmos DB - I removed these, accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Optimistic Concurrency](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/database-transactions-optimistic-concurrency#optimistic-concurrency-control).

When you do the ReadItemAsync, from the ItemResponse, obtain the [ETag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.itemresponse-1.etag?view=azure-dotnet#microsoft-azure-cosmos-itemresponse-1-etag).

On your Patch operation, pass in the `ItemRequestOptions` and specify the [IfMatchEtag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.requestoptions.ifmatchetag?view=azure-dotnet#microsoft-azure-cosmos-requestoptions-ifmatchetag) property matching the ETag you got from the Read.

If another concurrent modification happened, you will get a PreConditionFailure (HTTP 412) response (CosmosException with HTTP 412).

You then know something concurrently updated the same document, you can then repeat the cycle (Read -> conditional Patch).

Comment: That's absolutely fantastic, I had no idea about this mechanism. Thanks!

Comment: Would you say that it's a common thing to do? I mean in 2023 I cannot picture a serious database that would NOT handle concurrency, so I would imagine literally everyone working with ETags, but I find very few mentions of it and I'm scared to overdo it (for example I don't know if it's expensive). Am I to understand that the queries would still fail if there was a conflict, even without me explicitly comparing the ETags?

Comment: Cosmos DB covers different business scenarios, different consistency and latency and geo-replication requirements, etc. What is common is often biased by what I might have experienced in the present/past. There are plenty of users that want consistency in concurrent updates and they use this method. Not sure what you mean by queries failing, a query would not fail with HTTP 412 as far as I know. A query might deliver one version of the document (whatever it was committed when the query executed).

Comment: Thanks! My immediate thought is : Why would they call it "optimistic" concurrency as it's only enabling regular concurrency (as in : without it, concurrent updates might destroy data). But now I know! Thanks.